# Why does this syntax work in MySQL (matching column-pairs against column-pairs)?

Tags: mysql, syntax

Just now I needed to do something like the following query, and was surprised that it actually worked as intented. However I cannot find any documentation on it so I'm a little afraid about unknown side effects of this. Here's what I wrote:

```
select * from Table1 where (col1, col2) in (select col3, col4 from Table2)
```

This seems to be matching a pair of columns against a list of column-pairs. Is this how it is supposed to work, or can I expect some nasty surprises down the road?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems there is a page in the MySQL manual about that syntax : [12.2.9.5. Row Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/row-subqueries.html)

One of the given examples is this one (quoting) :

```
SELECT column1,column2,column3
       FROM t1
       WHERE (column1,column2,column3) IN
             (SELECT column1,column2,column3 FROM t2);
```

*Which is quite similar to your query.*

So I suppose it is officially supported.

The same page says (quoting) :

> Row constructors are legal in other
>   contexts as well. For example, the
>   following two statements are
>   semantically equivalent (although the
>   first one cannot be optimized until
>   MySQL 5.0.26):

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (column1,column2) = (1,1);
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = 1 AND column2 = 1;
```

So, even if the syntax you proposed is valid, the second one might be better, if you can use it, at least -- and more easy to read / understand ;-)

And you'll find plenty other stuff about subqueries from the page [12.2.9. Subquery Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

*(Yeah, wasn't easy to find ^^ )*

Comment: Yeah, subqueries, at least of this type, are part of the normal SQL standard I believe, so you shouldn't have to worry too much about portability this way.

Comment: @Brent : I've actually **never** seen this syntax -- so I was quite curious about it too ^^  (and I've learned one more thing, answering questions on SO ! )

Comment: Whoa, yeah, that *is* buried deep down under! Thanks!

Comment: @Vilx : you're welcome ! And thanks to you for the interesting question !

Comment: He, the fun thing is that I *guessed* at it - and it worked! :D